# How to Enable Multi Radio button Selection Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/wY63X/1/) in jsFiddle and let me know how I can enable multi selection in radio buttons and store the result in an array using jquery?

What I want is having options to chose one or many radio btns and eventually storing them in an array to store in a database. I have simple HTML form like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="items" value="Item One">Item One</input><br >
<input type="radio" name="items" value="Item Two">Item Two</input><br >
<input type="radio" name="items" value="Item Three">Item Three</input><br >
<input type="radio" name="items" value="Item Four">Item Four</input><br >
<input type="radio" name="items" value="Item Five">Item Five</input><br >
<input type="radio" name="items" value="Item Six">Item Six</input><br >
<br />
<input type='button' value='Display Selected' id='isSelect'>
<p>You Select :</p>
```

​    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

I am also using this jQuery code to store the value of selected item

```
enter code here
$("#isSelect").click(function () {
var result = $('input:radio[name=items]:checked').val();
$("#sel").html(result);
});​
```

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `checkboxes` instead, check this jsfiddle demo out http://jsfiddle.net/wY63X/3/

To store it as an array you can do this

```
var storedArray = new Array();
$('input[name="items"]').each(function(){
       storedArray.push($(this).val());
});
```